# Stabilizer group uniquely determines subspace

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, quadratic-forms

Let $(Q,V)$ be a quadratic space over an algebraically closed field $k$.
Let
$$ SO_Q(k):= \{ \sigma \in GL(V) : Q(\sigma v) = Q(v) \ \text{for all} \ v \in V \ \text{and} \det(\sigma) = 1 \}$$
Let $L \leq V$ be a linear subspace and let
$$H_L := \{ \sigma \in SO_Q(k) : \sigma L \subset L \}$$
be the subgroup of elements stabilising $L$.
I would like to prove the following lemma:

$\textbf{Lemma}$:
Let $W \leq V$ be a proper subspace of $V$ and assume that for all $\sigma \in H_L$ there holds $\sigma W \subset W$. Then, $W = L$ or $W = L^{\perp_Q}$, where $L^{\perp_Q}$ denotes the orthogonal complement of $L$ with respect to the bilinear form induced by the quadratic form $Q$.

I know how to prove the Lemma when $Q$ is positive definite.
I post the proof below.
I would like to know what happens when $Q$ is NOT positive definite.
Under what hypothesis on $L$ is the Lemma above true?

Outline of the proof in the positive definite case:

First, one notices that when $Q$ is positive definite $SO_Q(k)$ acts transitively on the set of vectors $\{v \in V : Q(v) = a \}$ where $a \in k$ is a fixed constant.
In particular, $SO_Q(k)$ acts transitively on the projectivization of $V$ (i.e. the set of lines in $V$), which we denote $\mathbb{P}(V)$

Now, assume for one second that $W \cap L \neq \{0\}$ or $W \cap L^{\perp_Q} \neq \{0\}$.
We treat the first case the second is identical.
Since $H_L$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}(L)$ and $W$ is $H_L$ invariant we get that $L \subset W$.
Now, either $L = W$, and so we are done. Or $W \cap L^{\perp_Q} \neq  \{0\}$.
In this case, using the fact that $H_L = H_{L^{\perp_Q}}$, we have that $H_L$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}( L^{\perp_Q} )$.
As $W$ is $H_L$ invariant, $ L^{\perp_Q} \subset W$. It follows that $W = V$ and so $W$ is not a proper subspace.

To conclude we reduce to the case $W \cap L \neq \{0\}$.
Let $w \in W$.
We can write $w = w_L + w_{L^{\perp}}$ with $w_L \in L$ and $w_{L^{\perp}} \in L^{\perp_Q}$. Take an element $h \in H_L$ which acts as the identity on $L^{\perp_Q}$ and non-trivially on $w_L$.
Then, $hw \in W$ and thus $hw - w \in W$.
Moreover,
$$ W \ni hw -w = hw_L + hw_{L^{\perp}} - w_L -w_{L^{\perp}} = hw_L - w_L \in L $$
Therefore, $hw_L - w_L \in W \cap L$ and it is not trivial by our choice of $h$. We have hence reduced to the case $W \cap L \neq \{0\}$ and the proof is complete.

From the proof of the positive definite case one observes that we may assume also in the non-positive definite case that $W \cap L \neq \emptyset$. Indeed, the proof given above works also for this case. From here however, I have not been able to advance. Indeed, to deduce that $L \subset W$ in the proof above we use that $H_L$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}(L)$ which is not necessarily true if $Q$ is NOT positive definite. Anyone has an idea about how to prove the fact above possibly adding some hypothesis on $L$ or the quadratic form $Q$. Thank you in advance !